# What movie is playing in this Android phone review?

Tags: story-identification, movie

At 3'37 in this phone review, a movie is playing. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [Avengers: Infinity War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War). The character is [Scarlet Witch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_Witch):

[image: Scarlet Witch]

Answer (score 3):

It's [Avengers: Infinity War](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154756/), specifically this scene near the start of the film where Scarlet Witch and Vision are attacked by Proxima Midnight and Corvus Glaive.